# How to select one of the rows after query?

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE1:

```
+-----------+----------+
|    CODE   |  TYPEID  |
+-----------+----------+
| 441       |  mn014   |
| 223       |  mn014   |
| 224       |  mn014   |
| 655       |  mn089   |
| 854       |  mn089   |
| 449       |  mn032   |
+-----------+----------+
```

TABLE2:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| CODE      | TAKENDTE | RTURNDTE |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| 441       | 25/08/14 | 01/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 03/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 01/02/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 655       | 25/08/14 | 07/01/15 |
| 854       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 449       | 25/08/14 | 06/01/15 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

I have selected all codes of the typeid mn014 that either don't exist in the second table or are NOT NULL in the RTURNDTE column in all instances they exist in table 2
using this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where typeid = 'mn014' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and
                        t2.rturndte is null
                 );
```

Now i can't figuire out how to select just one of the CODES selected at the end

any idea?

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

If you want any single result, add `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to the end of the query.

If you're looking for a specific code value, add `AND CODE = 'my code value'` to the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can `LIMIT` the result set and `ORDER BY` a column to sort the result set before limiting:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where typeid = 'mn014' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and
                        t2.rturndte is null
                 );
LIMIT 1
ORDER BY some_column
```